# Python: Monthly Sales - cannot get the commands to read from file

Tags: python

I am having a bit of trouble here. This is supposed to be reading and writing to the text file. When i try the commands it either does nothing or breaks on me. I know i am overlooking the slightest thing, any help would be appreciated, I have been trying this for hours 
Thank you

```
# a file in the current directory
FILENAME = "monthly_sales.txt"

# method for reading the monthly_sales file into a dictionary
def read_sales(sales):  
  with open(FILENAME, "r") as file:
    sales = {}
    for line in file:
      line = line.replace("\n", "")
      row = line.split("\t")
      sales[row[0]] = int(row[1])
  return sales

# method for editing the value in a month and writing it to the file
def edit_month(month):
  month = input("Three-letter Month: ")
  month = month.title()
  if month in sales.keys():
    amount = int(input("Sales Amount: "))
    amount = sales[month]
    print("Sales amount for {:s} is {:,.2f}.".format(month, amount))
    print()
  else:
    print("Invalid three-letter month.")
    print()

# method for writing the file
def write_sales(sales):  
  with open(FILENAME, "w") as file:    
    for month, amount in sales.items():
      file.write(month + "\t" + str(amount) + "\n")

def display_menu():
    print("Monthly Sales program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("view   - View sales for specified month")
    print("edit   - Edit sales for specified month")
    print("totals - View sales summary for year")
    print("exit   - Exit program")

def main():
    display_menu()
    sales = {}          
    while True:
        print()
        command = input("Command: ")
        command = command.lower()
        if command == "view":
            read_sales(sales)
        elif command == "edit":
            edit_month(month)            
        elif command == "totals":
            write_sales(sales)
        elif command == "exit":
            print("Bye!")
            break
        else:
            print("Unknown command. Please try again.")            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: when i type in the option for edit and then type in the month i want it says sales is not defined

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues...in summary:

- You were calling `edit_month(month)` but `month` is not defined at this point in the code, and you actually want to pass `sales` not `month` into `edit_month()` since you are creating or defining month within `edit_month()`; you also want to return `sales` from `edit_month()`
- You had a similar problem with `read_sales()` ... you need to assign the output of `read_sales()` to the variable `sales` inside `main()`
- There was also a flow issue where `read_sales()` was always reading from the file (even if the user made changes to the local, in-memory copy of sales).  I added a "load" command which calls `read_sales()` to load it from the file.  Then, for "view" I simply show a print out of the dictionary variable `sales`.
- Your command "totals" was actually writing to a file.  I added a `compute_totals()` function
- I added some error-checking when loading the sales file, and a default dictionary value with the months all set to zero
- Your dictionary values are integers; you may want to change those to floats for currency

Here is your code modified to work:

```
# a file in the current directory
FILENAME = "monthly_sales.txt"

# set a default value
sales_default = {'Jan': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Mar': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'May': 0, 'Jun': 0, 'Jul': 0, 'Aug': 0, 'Sep': 0, 'Oct': 0, 'Nov': 0, 'Dec': 0}

# method for reading the monthly_sales file into a dictionary
def read_sales():  
  sales = {}
  with open(FILENAME, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
      line = line.replace("\n", "")
      row = line.split("\t")
      sales[row[0]] = int(row[1])
  return sales

# method for editing the value in a month and writing it to the file
def edit_month(sales):
  month = input("Three-letter Month: ")
  month = month.title()
  if month in sales.keys():
    amount = int(input("Sales Amount: "))
    sales[month] = amount
    print("Sales amount for {:s} is {:,.2f}.".format(month, amount))
    print()
  else:
    print("Invalid three-letter month.")
    print()
  return sales

# method for writing the file
def write_sales(sales):  
  with open(FILENAME, "w") as file:    
    for month, amount in sales.items():
      file.write(month + "\t" + str(amount) + "\n")

def compute_totals(sales):
    totals = 0.0
    for month, amount in sales.items():
        totals += amount
    return totals

def display_menu():
    print("Monthly Sales program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("load   - Load sales from file")
    print("view   - View sales for specified month")
    print("edit   - Edit sales for specified month")
    print("totals - View sales summary for year")
    print("write -  Write sales to file")
    print("exit   - Exit program")

def main():
    display_menu()
    sales = {}          
    while True:
        print()
        command = input("Command: ")
        command = command.lower()
        if command == "load":
            try:
                sales = read_sales()
                print(sales)
            except:
                print("Could not load from sales file; using defaults")
                sales = sales_default
        elif command == "view":
            print(sales)
        elif command == "edit":
            sales = edit_month(sales)            
        elif command == "totals":
            print( compute_totals(sales) )
        elif command == "write":
            write_sales(sales)
        elif command == "exit":
            print("Bye!")
            break
        else:
            print("Unknown command. Please try again.")            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is example output when it is executed:

```
COMMAND MENU
load   - Load sales from file
view   - View sales for specified month
edit   - Edit sales for specified month
totals - View sales summary for year
write -  Write sales to file
exit   - Exit program

Command: view
{}

Command: load
{'Jan': 100, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 300, 'Apr': 400, 'May': 500, 'Jun': 600, 'Jul': 700, 'Aug': 800, 'Sep': 900, 'Oct': 1000, 'Nov': 1100, 'Dec': 1200}

Command: edit
Three-letter Month: mar
Sales Amount: 555
Sales amount for Mar is 555.00.


Command: view
{'Jan': 100, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 555, 'Apr': 400, 'May': 500, 'Jun': 600, 'Jul': 700, 'Aug': 800, 'Sep': 900, 'Oct': 1000, 'Nov': 1100, 'Dec': 1200}

Command: totals
8055.0

Command: write
```

Here is what your monthly_sales.txt file should look like (obviously the numerical values can be different -- but they should be integers as your code is currently written, and as explained above you may want to change these to floats):

```
Jan 100
Feb 200
Mar 555
Apr 400
May 500
Jun 600
Jul 700
Aug 800
Sep 900
Oct 1000
Nov 1100
Dec 1200
```